# Void array extension method does nothing

Tags: c#, arrays, extension-methods

I write an array and then I use my extension method to append to it:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] testInts = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    testInts.Append(6);

    Console.WriteLine("Test Integers\n");

    foreach (int variable in testInts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(variable));
    }            

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void Append(this int[] arr, int value)
{
    arr = arr.Concat(new[] { value }).ToArray();
}
```

But when it prints to console, it is still only 1, 2, 3, 4, 5? But when I just use

```
testInts = testInts.Concact(new[] { 6 }).ToArray()
```

It works just fine? Why is this and is there any way of resolving this issue?

**EDIT**

The whole point I used a void was so I didn't want to use

```
testInt = testInt.Append(6)
```

It HAS to just be `testInt.Append(6)`. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why this happens

When you pass the testInts array into the extension method, it does not really pass the variable, but only the reference. So when you do the assignment, it does indeed create the local array with the 6th value and assigns it to a local variable (not the original caller's).

You need to pass the variable by ref, but that is not possible for extension methods.

To understand this better check the [passing parameters by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters), with or without the ref keyword.

> Because the parameter is a reference to arr, it is possible to change the values of the array elements. However, the attempt to reassign the parameter to a different memory location only works inside the method and does not affect the original variable, arr.

#### Making it work with an extension method

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] testInts = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            testInts.Append(ref testInts,6);

            Console.WriteLine("Test Integers\n");

            foreach (int variable in testInts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(variable));
            }            

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue.");
        }
}

public static class Extentions {
    public static void Append(this int[] arr, ref int[] arr2, int value)
    {
        arr2 = arr.Concat(new[] { value }).ToArray();
    }
}
```

#### Another way to make it work

If you are to make a new assignment, it does not make sense to even make an extension method.

```
public static int[] Append(int[] arr, int value)
{
    return arr.Concat(new[] { value }).ToArray();
}

// use like this
arr = Append(arr, 6);
```

Comment: is there any way to reference the array within the extention instead of passing it as it will always be the same array?

Comment: Not in any proper way. You could declare it on a global scope and assign the new array to the global variable, but this goes against a lot of good coding practices to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

That is because an array is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) and **NOT** a [value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types).

you need to "replace" the array with a new array in order to get the desired result.

**This is working like you want:**

```
 testInts = testInts.Concat(new[] { 6 }).ToArray()
```

**Because** you set the array again when you passing an array (reference type object) you are passing a pointer that points the array (in the app memory) that is why you need to replace it. read about [Pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) if you want to understand this topic better.

Here a fixed version of your code, see that the extension method is now returning a new array of integer.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] testInts = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    testInts =  testInts.Append(6);
    Console.WriteLine("Test Integers\n");
    foreach (int variable in testInts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(variable));
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static int[] Append(this int[] arr, int value)
{
    arr = arr.Concat(new[] { value }).ToArray();
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with value types or reference types. It has to do with passing parameters by value vs by reference

Answer (score -1):

If you debug your application, when you are in Append(.., ..) method, you'll observe "arr" has update value (1..6) after Concat() operation, but as soon as control comes out of Append(.., ..) method your "testInts" will have old value (1..5).

Try with updated code.

```
public static int[] Append(this int[] arr, int value)
        {
            arr = arr.Concat(new[] { value }).ToArray();
            return arr;
        }
```

and in main(..)

```
testInts = testInts.Append(6);
```

this way you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Arrays are not value types. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb985948(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN >This means that all arrays are always reference types

Comment: Thanks @AthanasiosKataras for correction. I'll edit my comment.